# How to properly mock an imported library?

Tags: go, mocking

I have an import:

```
import {
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/route53"
}
```

Which I then use to work with host zones in AWS Route 53.
I see that the code I created works properly now with the current setup.

To simplify development process, I want to create a mock of the library methods I use while developing.

I have a key in config, like this `env="development"` or `env="production"`.

My plan is to add my own object that is `route53` with the needed methods and import it if the env is development.

How do I do it better?
Does golang support conditional importing, like this:

```
if (env=="development") {
    import "./route53-mock"
} else {
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/route53"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Go does not support conditional importing–at least not in the current stable version.

An `interface` with the methods you need to use is a good fit to solve this problem:

```
type TrafficPolicyLister interface {
   ListTrafficPolicies(*route53.ListTrafficPoliciesInput) (*route53.ListTrafficPoliciesOutput, error)
}
```

Now you can use the interface wherever you would previously use `route53.Route53`. In production you would pass an object of type `route53.Route53` (which implements that interface) but during development you can pass a mock:

```
type TrafficPolicyListerMock struct {}

func (t *TrafficPolicyListerMock) ListTrafficPolicies(input *route53.ListTrafficPoliciesInput) (*route53.ListTrafficPoliciesOutput, error) {
    // return whatever you want your mock to return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do unit testing, read the [answer of @csm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42243577/372172).

If you want to have a development environment (not unit testing), you should probably look at [minio](https://www.minio.io/), effectively a self-hosted S3 implementation. You should use environment variable to inject the S3 endpoints. Then you're free to use your own minio server for your development.

Answer (score -1):

"Does golang support conditional importing [?]". Answer: No. Just take a look at the language spec.

"How do I do it better?" Answer: Route calls to route53 through your own package which switches between mock and real route53 depending on your environment/build -tags/cmdlineargs/whatever.